# How to find out what the codes for the states of an object are?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Right now I get the nodes of a cluster using `Get-ClusterNode` and then pipe it to `ConvertTo-Json` to serialize the data. Unfortunately, the `State` property turns from a nice string like `Paused` or `Up` into integers. I want to display this information on a GUI, so I was thinking of having a dictionary with the state number as keys and the actual strings as the values (I don't mind the states being saved as numbers at all).

The problem is I have no good way of finding out what number means what. I used `Get-Member` to find out that each cluster is of type `Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterNode`, but Googling gave me no documentation. I compared the JSON output with `Format-List *` to find out `Up` is `0`, but I need the codes for all states. There are other items such as networks that also have a `State` property with apparently different interpretations, so I could be caught spending way too much time trying to sneakily decipher it like this.

Is there some sort of resource or cmdlet that can just get me the info straight away?

Comment: [Collecting Name and Integer values from enum types in PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/collecting-name-and-integer-values-from-enum-types-in-powershell)

Comment: Thanks a million, saved tons of hours of me pulling my hair out!

Comment: @beatcracker You should post that as an answer so I can accept it and so if anyone else comes across this question they can also use that resource